# ComponentView has unnecessary extra inset at top

Tags: java, swing

I am having trouble with creating a custom document in which I need ComponentViews (as I want to use normal swing component listeners).

This is how it currently looks like:
[image: Wrong offset]

Obviously, the extra padding (or as I found out, the `minorInset` inside the parent's BoxView) is wrong and shifts the whole component down a few pixels, 6 to be exact.

I am adding the component as follows:

```
public class InlineLabelTest extends JFrame {

    public InlineLabelTest() {
        try {
            final JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
            textPane.setEditorKit(new InlineLabelKit());

            final LabelDocument document = (LabelDocument) textPane.getDocument();
            document.insertString(0, "Lorem ipsum", new SimpleAttributeSet());
            document.insertLabel(document.getLength(), "dateAndTime");

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(new JScrollPane(textPane));

        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new InlineLabelTest().setVisible(true));
    }


    private static class InlineLabelKit extends StyledEditorKit {
        private LabelViewFactory factory;


        @Override
        public ViewFactory getViewFactory() {
            if (factory == null) {
                factory = new LabelViewFactory();
            }

            return factory;
        }

        @Override
        public Document createDefaultDocument() {
            return new LabelDocument();
        }

    }

    private static class LabelDocument extends DefaultStyledDocument {

        public void insertLabel(int offset, String label) {
            final ArrayList<ElementSpec> specs = new ArrayList<>();
            final JButton flag = new JButton(label);

            // The combination of the border and the font adds the inset
            flag.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.ORANGE));
            flag.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 10));

            final SimpleAttributeSet inner = new SimpleAttributeSet();
            StyleConstants.setComponent(inner, flag);

            specs.add(new ElementSpec(inner, ElementSpec.StartTagType));
            specs.add(new ElementSpec(inner, ElementSpec.ContentType, label.toCharArray(), 0, label.length()));
            specs.add(new ElementSpec(inner, ElementSpec.EndTagType));

            try {
                insert(offset, specs.toArray(new ElementSpec[specs.size()]));

            } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private static class LabelViewFactory implements ViewFactory {

        @Override
        public View create(Element elem) {
            switch (elem.getName()) {
                case AbstractDocument.SectionElementName: return new BoxView(elem, View.Y_AXIS);
                case AbstractDocument.ParagraphElementName: return new ParagraphView(elem);
                case StyleConstants.ComponentElementName: return new ComponentView(elem);
                case StyleConstants.IconElementName: return new IconView(elem);
                default: return new LabelView(elem);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

**It seems as if the combination of the custom border and font (Or any change that affects its default size) creates the inset.**

How can I get rid of that extra padding? Why does the system even add a BoxView around the ComponentView? Is there anything I missed?

Much thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you post a SSCCE?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Done, I actually figured out what exactly causes the issue, but now why it happens. It seems like the combination of the border and font size makes the button bigger than it should be. It does no seem to take a smaller font size into account, thus adding the padding.

Comment: Okay, i finally figured it out on my own, as shown by my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after the whole day spent researching and going through debugging this, I found out that I manually have to set the Y alignment on the component that I want to set.

What actually happened (simply speaking) is, that the texts baseline was at roughly 85% of the text's height, while the components baseline defaulted back to 50% (as its not a text, but a box), thus adding the difference of 35% as inset from the top.

This can easily be fixed by specifying the Y-Alignment on the component you want to add:

```
JButton component = new JButton(text);
FontMetrics fontMetrics = component.getFontMetrics(component.getFont());
LineMetrics metrics = fontMetrics.getLineMetrics(text, component.getGraphics());

float ascent = metrics.getAscent(), descent = metrics.getDescent();
component.setAlignmentY(ascent / (ascent + descent));
```